# Why this error occurs: Subquery returned more than 1 value

Tags: c#, sql

My Sql Query

```
 SELECT BOOKING_TIME,
       Contact_No,
       (FName+LName)AS NAME ,
       E_MAIL,

  (SELECT ZM.ZONE_NAME
   FROM Zone_Master ZM
   INNER JOIN BOOKINGS ON ZM.Zone_ID = BOOKINGS.Zone_ID)AS ZONE_NAME,
       City,
       Addr_1,
       Addr_2,
       PIN,

  (SELECT PROJECTS.PROJECT_NAME
   FROM PROJECTS
   INNER JOIN BOOKINGS ON PROJECTS.PROJECT_ID=BOOKINGS.PROJECT_ID)AS PROJECT_NAME
FROM BOOKINGS
```

Answer (score 4):

You're getting that error because of your subqueries:

```
(SELECT ZM.ZONE_NAME
 FROM Zone_Master ZM
 INNER JOIN BOOKINGS ON ZM.Zone_ID = BOOKINGS.Zone_ID) AS ZONE_NAME
```

And:

```
(SELECT PROJECTS.PROJECT_NAME
 FROM PROJECTS
 INNER JOIN BOOKINGS ON PROJECTS.PROJECT_ID = BOOKINGS.PROJECT_ID) AS PROJECT_NAME
```

You're getting multiple records back and trying to store them in a single field.

Answer (score 3):

Here is your query:

```
SELECT  BOOKING_TIME, Contact_No,(FName+LName)AS NAME, E_MAIL,
        (SELECT ZM.ZONE_NAME
         FROM Zone_Master ZM INNER JOIN
              BOOKINGS
              ON ZM.Zone_ID = BOOKINGS.Zone_ID
       ) AS ZONE_NAME,
       City, Addr_1, Addr_2, PIN,
       (SELECT PROJECTS.PROJECT_NAME
        FROM PROJECTS INNER JOIN
             BOOKINGS
             ON PROJECTS.PROJECT_ID=BOOKINGS.PROJECT_ID
       ) AS PROJECT_NAME
FROM BOOKINGS;
```

Either subquery could be returning more than one row.  In a subselect in the `select` clause, you can only return one value.  I think there is an easy fix.  You probably want correlated subuqeries, so just remove the `BOOKINGS` table from each subquery:

```
SELECT  BOOKING_TIME, Contact_No, (FName+LName)AS NAME, E_MAIL,
        (SELECT ZM.ZONE_NAME
         FROM Zone_Master ZM
         WHERE ZM.Zone_ID = BOOKINGS.Zone_ID
       ) AS ZONE_NAME,
       City,Addr_1,Addr_2,PIN,
       (SELECT PROJECTS.PROJECT_NAME
        FROM PROJECTS 
        WHERE PROJECTS.PROJECT_ID = BOOKINGS.PROJECT_ID
       )AS PROJECT_NAME
FROM BOOKINGS;
```

These are now "correlated subqueries".  In this case, they should each return at most one row.

Another way to express this query is using `join` syntax:

```
SELECT BOOKING_TIME, Contact_No, (FName+LName)AS NAME, E_MAIL,
       ZM.ZONE_NAME,
       City, Addr_1, Addr_2, PIN,
       p.PROJECT_NAME
FROM BOOKINGS b LEFT OUTER JOIN
     Zone_Master zm
     on ZM.Zone_ID = BOOKINGS.Zone_ID LEFT OUTER JOIN
     PROJECTS p
     on p.PROJECT_ID = b.PROJECT_ID
```